# COMException with interopServices C# in Excel only with xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

Getting exception

```
{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC}
```

while adding the validation on xlsx columns.

Code line causing the exception:

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E:E", misValue).Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateCustom, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "\"\"");
```

Above code works fine with `.xlx` but fails with `.xlsx`.